# Why does sharing layers in keras make building the graph extremely slow (tensorflow backend)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building a graph where the input is split into a list of tensors of length 30. I then use a shared RNN layer on each element of the list.

It takes ~ 1 minute until the model is compiled. Does it have to be like this (why?) or is there anything I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
shared_lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)
shared_dense = TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

inp_train = keras.layers.Input([None, se.action_space, 3])

#  Split each possible measured label into a list:
inputs_train = [ keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, i, :])(inp_train) for i in range(se.action_space) ]

# Apply the shared weights on each tensor:
lstm_out_train = [shared_lstm(x) for x in inputs_train]
dense_out_train = [(shared_dense(x)) for x in lstm_out_train]

# Merge the tensors again:
out_train = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.stack(x, axis=2))(dense_out_train)

# "Pick" the unique element along where the inp_train tensor is == 1.0 (along axis=2, in the next time step, of the first dimension of axis=3)
# (please disregard this line if it seems too complex)
shift_and_pick_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x[0][:, :-1, :, 0] * x[1][:, 1:, :, 0], axis=2))

out_train = shift_and_pick_layer([out_train, inp_train])


m_train = keras.models.Model(inp_train, out_train)
```

Comment: How about trying `TimeDistributed` also on `LSTM` and `shared_dense`?

Comment: An LSTM takes a sequence - not a time step (slice) so I do not understand how this might help. If you link to a code snippet maybe I would understand.